# it is possible to setup manual replication for aurora postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

i wont to setup replication between the master and slave streaming replication (physical replication )  it is possible in aurora PostgreSQL

i have tried to logical replication setup for Aurora PostgreSQL i wont to setup physical replication

Answer (score 0):

Replication with Aurora PostgreSQL
When it comes to replication with Aurora PostgreSQL, you have the following options:

- PostgreSQL native logical replication
- PostgreSQL logical replication using the pglogical extension
- Physical replication with Aurora global database

REF: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/understand-replication-capabilities-in-amazon-aurora-postgresql/